# Effect of Clemmensen reduction on carboxylic acids

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

Does the Clemmensen reduction have any effect on the carboxyl group $\ce{-COOH}$ if it is attached to some organic compound? If yes, what does it get reduced to?

Comment: You're putting zinc in acid, so there will be a reaction, but maybe not the one you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that there would be removal of carbonyl group because the -cooh group would be in resonance and also clemmensen reduction is preffered for aldehydes and ketones to remove oxygen .
More help would be afyer understanding its mechanism here[Mechanism of clemmensen reduction](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/clemmensen-reduction.shtm)

Also the zinc(amphoteric) might react with the acid giving salt.